# Get Sub Directory Files and Add to String Array

Tags: c#, arrays, fileinfo, directoryinfo

I am trying to insert the full directory path as well as the file and extension into the String Array but I am not getting it, any chance someone has a better way to do this.

I am using the nested for each because there is a list of Directories below the main directory "directoryInfo" that have the files I am looking for.

```
string[] moveLocalFiles;
List<String> localFiles = new List<String>();
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sourceFilePath);            

try
{
    foreach (DirectoryInfo i in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
    {                                       
       foreach(FileInfo f in i.GetFiles(".twb"))
       {
           localFiles.Add(f.ToString());
       }  


    moveLocalFiles = localFiles.ToArray();

    foreach (string filePath in moveLocalFiles)
    {
     //do something
    }
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Just a side note if you `throw ex;` you will lose the Stack Trace. It is better to simply `throw;` unless of course that behaviour is intended.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Ill keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan says you're definitely missing a "*" in your filter, but more than that you should use the FullName property, like this:

```
localFiles.Add(f.FullName);
```

Also (but this could be a desired behavior) you're browsing only the first level of subdirectories of "sourceFilePath" (excluding that directory as well).
And also in the sample code there's a missing bracket just before the "catch" line (but I understand this is just a sample code that you pasted here and not your real program).
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the FullName property, that did it for me. Also, there is only one layer to view for this directory, and there always will be. Thank you for pointing that out though. Basically the folder structure is always the same and there will always be one file in the first layer of sub directories.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a * before .twb in the GetFiles call.

Comment: That actually makes sense. I am not able to get those files. However, it is still only returning the Filenames not the Path and File name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the full path to each Directory and File you can either use your own method just altered slightly:

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo i in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
{                                       
    foreach (FileInfo f in i.GetFiles("*.twb")) //The * is a wildcard search for anything
    {
        localFiles.Add(f.FullName); //FullName returns the full path
    }
}
```

Or you can use the `System.IO.Directory` class like so:

```
foreach (string i in Directory.GetDirectories("path to directory"))
{                                       
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(i, "*.twb")) //The * is a wildcard search for anything
    {
        localFiles.Add(f);
    }
}
```